# MVC3 - Controller index action called twice every time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using MVC Razor
I have a *very* simple test.  The "logger" writes messages to a log file

TestController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  logger.Trace("Test Index Called");
  return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<html>
<head><title>Testing</title></head>
<body><h3>This is a test</h3></body>
</html>
```

global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default",
  "{controller}/{action}",
  new { action = "Index" }
);
```

When I run the code, the log file shows this:

2011-12-15 10:16:09.4475: Test Index Called

2011-12-15 10:16:09.4475: Test Index Called

Notice that the timestamp for both calls are at exactly the same time?  I've eliminated the issue where people have said that empty src attributes on a image tag and/or javascript functions not returning.

I've made this as simple as I possibly can - but the index action is being called twice in rapid succession.

Help?

Comment: what about running project in debug mode and putting a breakpoint on a logger ?

Comment: The breakpoint stops once.  I created a new project and only references the logger - and it's logging only once.  I'm thinking there is something else going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that it's not the logger that writes two entries for each call? (For instance if you have configured two filters for the same logging target)

It's highly unlikely that ASP.NET can process the same action two times at the exact same millisecond.

Comment: I had included the logger with the same variable name in a place where I shouldn't have